# ComboBox without text area

Tags: c#, winforms, outlook

I want to have a ComboBox without a text-area in a custom task pane, so there is only the arrow which opens a dropdown menu but without any text next to the button. I'm using WinForms and I can't find any solution how to remove the text area.

[image: Button with dropdown menu]

BR

Comment: Looks like a combination of button and context menu. Why do you want to do this with combobox?

Comment: how the user could know which one is select after a click if you remove the area ? No reason to use combobox here.

Comment: Add a label on top of area you want to hide

Comment: There is an action behind every element, I don't want to keep the selected index

Comment: @user2414460: "There is an action behind every element" - this is menu.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a list you can do this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBox1.Visible = !listBox1.Visible;
}

private void listBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBox1.Visible = false;
}

private void listBox1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBox1.Visible = false;
}
```

But if you need actions behind every entry a Menu is the more natural choice...

Answer (score 0):

[Windows Forms Toolkit](https://wftoolkit.codeplex.com/)
have a component named **SplitButton** that is very similar at what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I created a Button with a `ContextMenuStrip`, this was exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Question title is very misleading then.

Comment: I didn't know about ContextMenuStrip before